# what is the difference between factory and abstract factory design pattern in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

1) Is factory implemented by concrete factory class with if else check on type and create objects depending on type ?
   OR
   we have Interface factory with abstract create method 
   and we implement this interface in concrete factory class for each different types of objects and we instantiate obj of that particular kind of object.

2) How abstract factory is different from factory ? is it just factory of factory ?

3) how do we change the if else conditions for creating particular kind of objects ? if we remove if else, then does it become abstract factory ?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that if you open up any books with "Design Patterns" in the name or search SO you will find at least 1 thorough explanation for this question.

Comment: The GOF patterns do not include any "factory" pattern - you might be referring to the ["factory method"](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~aaguiar/as/gof/hires/pat3cfso.htm) pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Factories are a whole group of techniques for making objects.

An abstract factory is an interface to something which can create an object for you. You do not specify how it makes it, the instance of the factory has its own way of making that particular object or group of objects.

A factory method is a method on a class to help you make an instance of that class.

You don't generally use if/else statements in factories because:

1. With an abstract factory the instance of factory you have determines how it will work
2. With a factory method the particular method you call determines the sort of thing you're making.

A good jumping on point is here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern

Answer (score 1):

**`How abstract factory is different from factory ?`**

Answer to your question is : In number of ways.
First try to figure out the basics of `Factory` and `Abstract Factory`.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbstractFactoryVsFactoryMethod

`Is it a factory of factory ?`
 yes you can reffer an abstract factory as a factory of factory.

**Summary in short :**

`Factory Method` is used to create one product (More specifically its like a single method only) but Abstract Factory is like an Object. You can create families of related or dependent products by using `abstract factory`.

`Factory` Method pattern exposes a method to the client for creating the object whereas in case of `Abstract Factory` they expose a family of related objects which may consist of these Factory methods.

`AbstractFactory` pattern uses composition to delegate responsibility of creating object to another class while Factory design pattern uses inheritance and relies on derived class or sub class to create object.

The idea behind the `Factory` pattern is that it allows for the case where a client doesn't know what concrete classes it will be required to create at runtime, but just wants to get a class that will do the job while `AbstractFactory` pattern is best utilized when your system has to create multiple families of products or you want to provide a library of products without exposing the implementation details.

**Some Code Example :**

Factory Method :

```
 class A {
public void doSomething() {
    Foo f = makeFoo();
    f.whatever();   
}

protected Foo makeFoo() {
    return new RegularFoo();
}
}

class B extends A {
protected Foo makeFoo() {
    //subclass is overriding the factory method 
    //to return something different
    return new SuperFoo();
}
}
```

Abstract Factory :

```
 class A {
private Factory factory;

public A(Factory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}

public void doSomething() {
    //The concrete class of "f" depends on the concrete class
    //of the factory passed into the constructor. If you provide a
    //different factory, you get a different Foo object.
    Foo f = factory.makeFoo();
    f.whatever();
}
}

interface Factory {
Foo makeFoo();
Bar makeBar();
```

}

However I really didn't understand the purpose of your if-else here. Now comming down to your phrase 
`creating particular kind of objects`. yes you can do it by passing the concreate class object to the factory much like the above code snippet in the example.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can think in a Factory as an API for creating objects. The instantiation logic is not exposed to the client and logic may be implemented with a series of "if-else", etc

An Abstract factory act as a single point of access when multiple concrete factories are available.  This is useful for example for creating objects to target different environments, i.e. The implementation of an Abstract Factory to create GUI components may load dynamically a concrete Factory to produce concrete GUI components for Windows OS. Another concrete Factory may be available to produce components for Linux OS.